# check if dropdown's first option has selected attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dropdown listing last 5 years from current year, current year being selected explicitly. Here is my code:

```
var nDate = new Date();
    var year = nDate.getFullYear();
    $('#yearddl').append('<option value>Select Year</option>');
    for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            $('#yearddl').append('<option selected value =' + year + '>' + year + '</option>');
        }
        else {
            $('#yearddl').append('<option value =' + year + '>' + year + '</option>');
        }

        year = year - 1;
    }
```

Now, my requirement is that how can I check that whether first option, which would in any case be the current year, has selected attribute. Basically, I want to remove selected option from here and give it to some other option.

Comment: why you are adding `select year` do not add that. :P By default `Current Year` will be selected . ;)

Comment: @JoëlSalamin Well, I don't have the knowledge of  `:selected` pseudo selector, and yes, the answer was very straight forward. Besides this, it was just a part of what I was doing

Comment: @UnknownUser I didn't noticed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#yearddl option:nth-child(2)').is(":selected")
```

Comment: Almost there, but `first-child` will select `<option value>Select Year</option>`

Comment: Sorry for the carelessness, edited to take the second option.

Comment: `is(':selected')` is used for whether it(option) is selected or not. for saying selected you can use `prop` or `attr`

Answer (score 2):

Do not keep `selected` attribute while creating options. Once the `options` are generated, you can use `$('#yearddl option[value='+nDate.getFullYear()+']')` selector to set the `selected` property.

Try this:

```js
var nDate = new Date();
var year = nDate.getFullYear();
$('#yearddl').append('<option value>Select Year</option>');
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    $('#yearddl').append('<option value =' + year + '>' + year + '</option>');
  year = year - 1;
}
$('#yearddl option[value='+nDate.getFullYear()+']').prop('selected',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='yearddl'>
  <option value='2099' selected>2099</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/0kybe9po/1/)

Comment: but I need current year selected initially on page load

Comment: Note: `selected` attribute should be removed from the previously selected option (in more real life example).

Comment: @RayonDabre I meant that if you'd like to programmatically select one option and then select another you should remove `selected` attribute from previously selected option first.

Comment: @RayonDabre Isn't it the same thing that you are using `.prop()` method and put `selected` as the attribute. As with your method also you are adding an attribute to current year option. Also what I was searching for is the answer given by nemesis_sun.

Comment: @AmitKaushal, [__It is not the same thing__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) Also note that, If _current_ year is not the `2nd` child in the options list then other answer will not work as it is based on the index of the `option`. Mine is based on the value of the `option` which will work irrespective of the index of the option..

Comment: @RayonDabre Yes, you are right. Initially I thought the other way of doing the stuff in which I have to find the index. Your's is also correct. I was not able to think your way